# difference network and host address of destination in a route

Tags: linux, router

I learn a doc at [here](http://linux-ip.net/html/routing-tables.html)

it say ,destination address of a route entries, can be a network or host address (primary key).
what the difference between network and host address?

for example two entries below:(gayteway:192.168.100.254)

```
192.168.100.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.248 metric 100
```

&

```
192.168.100.254/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.248 metric 100
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the behavior is the same for each route. But setting a host address is hopefully possible because you can set a route to a host only (with a netmask of 255.255.255.255).

Some operating systems, like CentOS, don't accept a host address if the netmask is different from 255.255.255.255 (you'll got an invalid argument error). You must set the network address in order to add your route.